# ul hidden by overlapping div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a navigation menu using nested `ul`. When the top `ul` is hovered over it uses jQuery's `.slidedown()` to display the submenu `ul`.

This part works fine.

The problem I run into is when the submenu is displayed the lower portions (bottom `li`) are overlapped by a div further down the doc and I am unable to click on those sub menu items. 
Here is the HTML. The question is simply how do I specify which element should be in the foreground when I have overlapping elements?

Comment: 'Here is the HTML'. Okay, where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack order of elements is determined by the [`z-index`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531188(VS.85).aspx) CSS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
z-index: x;
```

where x is the z-index,

the higher the z-index, the more on top the element

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [z-index CSS property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Look into the z-index property in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Something went bad with you're code tags...

But it sounds like you might be looking for the z-index? Elements with a higher z-index would be above the other elements.

So on your navigation you would want:

z-index: 1; (or maybe higher if you want)

and be sure to also have

position: relative;

set as well.